# Name of solving equation by generating system of equations from similar variable power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a name for solving something like this?

$(a+b)s^3 + cs^2+(d+a)s+b=5s^3+4s^2+s+5$

by then setting

$a+b = 5$

$c=4$

$d+a=1$

$b=5$,

$\therefore a= 0, d=1$

Comment: Equating coefficients ?

Comment: Sounds like [equating coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equating_coefficients). You are allowed to do that if you know that the polynomials must be identical. In the case of this example, it's enough if you know that the equality holds for $4$ distinct values of $s$.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I think every time I've been shown it that I've never actually been told its name.